# how to redirect after form submission with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery validate plugin to valide a contact form before it is submitted.

The problem is that I should redirect to a 'thank you' page after a successful form submission.

Is this possible?

My validation code looks like this:

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
  //debug: true,

  rules: {

    fullname: "required",

    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
    window.location.href = "/confirm.html";
  }

});
```

for some reason

window.location.href = "/confirm.html");

is never executed.

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: That's because you submit the form so the line below is never executed. Either submit the form using ajax and redirect based on whether that's successful or do the redirection in you  server side code.

Comment: thanks Ashkan, you pointed me in the right direction. Luckily the Simple Form service has the ability to submit forms through Ajax

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I managed to redirect to a 'thank you' page after a vaild form submission to Simple Form. This has to be done trough an ajax call:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#contactForm").validate({
rules: {
    fullname: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },

  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: "http://getsimpleform.com/messages/ajax?form_api_token=my-secret-token",
          data: $("#contactForm").serialize()
        }).done(function() {
      //callback which can be used to show a thank you message
      //and reset the form
      window.location.href = "/confirm.html";
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

No I'm able to validate a contact form and submit it to the Simple Form service, and then redirect to a 'thank you' page, all without any server side code :smile: